# Angular 5: Add Class to particular index LI where checkbox is checked

Tags: angular

on change, If the checkbox is checked I want to add an active class on LI for a
particular index and if not checked then remove active class.

TS file

```
 test = [];
```

HTML file

```
 <li *ngFor="let item of test; let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="change($event, item, i)"> 
  <span class="active"> {{item}} </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Try: `[ngClass]`?

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxmekl

Comment: Try `[ngClass]="{'active':item.checked}"` !

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a class to all the elements checked, you need to store in a variable the values checked. normally we iterate over an array of object, but if you iterate over an array of string you need declare a new variable that was an array of boolean

```
checked:boolean[]=[];
```

Then, use [ngModel]

```
<li *ngFor="let item of test; let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked[i]" > 
  <span [ngClass]="{'active' : checked[i]}"> {{item}} </span>
</li>
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxmekl-jwb4fx?file=app/select-multiple-example.html)

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, can we achieve this without using [(ngModel)].

Comment: You can replace [(ngModel)] by `(change)="checked[i]=$event.target.checked"` but I don't see the advantage about this: you need store what values are checked in a variable (in an array). If the problem is used inside a ReactiveForm you can use [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use one local variable which will hold the value of the currently selected index
2. Use `event.target.checked` property to determine the checked or unchecked value
3. To set the class dynamically you can use `[ngClass]` with condition

So the HTML code will be:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of test; let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="change($event, item, i)"> 
  <span [ngClass]="{'active' : i == selectedIndex}"> {{item}} </span>
</li>
```

TS:

```
selectedIndex: number;

change(event, item, i) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    this.selectedIndex = i;
  }
  else {
    this.selectedIndex = -1;
  }
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxmekl)

> EDIT:

You can be done this without `[(ngModel)]` but with some modification in the current JSON data if that is a list of string then:

Expecting a JSON list to be:

```
test: any[] = [{ name: 'Extra cheese' }, { name: 'Mushroom' }, { name: 'Extra Onion' }, { name: 'Tommatos' }];
```

and then change function:

```
change(event, item, i) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    item.checked = true;
  }
  else {
    item.checked = false;
  }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of test; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="change($event, item, i)"> 
  <span [ngClass]="{'active' : item.checked}"> {{item.name}} </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, Prashant, it's working fine, but [active] class should be removed when I unchecked the checkbox only. 

For now active class removes when I checked the second one.

Comment: @SunilYadav yes, so that is your expected, it is checked the only single checkbox at a time